# Selectfield .... value vs text?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

Here is my selectField.

```
{
                xtype: 'selectfield',
                flex: 1,
                itemId: 'sorter_Selector',
                maxHeight: 50,
                label: 'Sort by',
                options: [
                    {
                        text: 'Name',
                        value: 'strTitle'
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Date of Project',
                        value: 'dateRelease'
                    }
                ],
                usePicker: false,
                listeners: [
                    {
                        fn: function(element, eOpts) {
                            var sorting = Ext.getStore('configstore').last().get('Sorting');

                            this.suspendEvents();
                            this.setValue(sorting);
                            this.resumeEvents();
                        },
                        event: 'painted'
                    }
                ]
            }
```

For some reason if I try to retrieve the value of an option.

would it be selectfield.getValue() or selectfield.getOptions().

the value field of each of my options is set to the text field and not to the defined value field...

Why? That does not make any sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had my language system overriding the Value field and not the text field, that why I was getting Text in getValue().